# Can't get sqlite database working?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have  one table working(one called DATABASE_CREATE1) and that table still works but when i try to insert data into the second table i get this error no idea how to fix it tryed for ages on how to fix it but had no luck any ideas:

```
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table quick_mute has no column named row_id_quick_mute: , while compiling: INSERT INTO quick_mute(row_id_quick_mute, alarm_id) VALUES(?, ?);
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at com.seanoneill.android.SilentPhone.DatabaseStore.createQuickMuteEntry(DatabaseStore.java:316)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at com.seanoneill.android.SilentPhone.HoldsEverything$1.onClick(HoldsEverything.java:163)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
06-13 23:56:21.179: E/Database(8840):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_QUICK + " ("
    + kEY_ROWID_QUICK_MUTE + "text not null, "
    + END_TIME_QUICK  + " text not null,"
    + ALARM_ID_QUICK + " text not null );";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1=
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + kEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + END_KEY_TIME  + " text not null,"
    + START_TIME_12_HOUR  + " text not null,"
    + END_TIME_12_HOUR  + " text not null,"
    + COVERT_DAYS + " text not null,"
    + KEY_STATE  + " text not null,"
    + MUTE_TITLE + " text not null, "
    + ALARM_MODE + " text not null, "
    +ALARM_ID+ " text not null,"
    + START_KEY_TIME  + " text not null  );";
```

creating database

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1);
}
```

here is code for insert into database

```
public void createQuickMuteEntry(String endTime, String alarmid) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(kEY_ROWID_QUICK_MUTE, endTime ); /
    initialValues.put(ALARM_ID, alarmid);
    databaseConnect.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_QUICK, null, initialValues);
}
```

Insert statment

```
getDatabaseInfo.createQuickMuteEntry("dfdf", "dfdf");
```

update:
//quick mute

```
public static final String END_TIME_QUICK = "quick_mute_end_time"; 
public static final String ALARM_ID_QUICK = "quick_mute_id";
public static final String kEY_ROWID_QUICK_MUTE = "row_id_quick_mute";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message:

```
SQLiteException: table quick_mute has no column named row_id_quick_mute: , while compiling: INSERT INTO quick_mute(row_id_quick_mute, alarm_id) VALUES(?, ?);
```

you missed out column:

```
row_id_quick_mute
```

in table

```
quick_mute
```

Upon further inspection, this is caused by faulty `CREATE` syntax.

Take a look at this code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_QUICK + " ("
    + kEY_ROWID_QUICK_MUTE + "text not null, "
    + END_TIME_QUICK  + " text not null,"
    + ALARM_ID_QUICK + " text not null );";
```

You should notice that in this line:

```
+ kEY_ROWID_QUICK_MUTE + "text not null, "
```

the `text` part is right next to `"`, without space between it.

Comment: i added code to this post above and i have quick mute column in ... could you look at updated code thanks

Comment: Thanks so much for that i would have never found this problem. I have a good bit of database code in my app and only new now from your answer that a space between text and " matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a space before `text`...

```
kEY_ROWID_QUICK_MUTE + "text not null, "
```